# Do nothing in :windo if condition does not apply

Tags: vimscript

Consider following autocommand

```
if exists('##OptionSet')
  augroup update_netrw_window
    autocmd!
    autocmd OptionSet wildignore
            \ let currwin=winnr()
            \ | windo
            \ | if &ft=='netrw'
            \ |   execute "normal \<c-l>"
            \ | else
            \ |   let a = 1
            \ | endif
            \ | execute currwin . 'wincmd w'
  augroup END
endif
```

I do not want to execute `"normal \<c-l>"` for non-netrw windows.
As a workaround I have added a simple assignment `let a = 1`.
However, I would like to replace this with something that truely does nothing.
I cannot remove the else branch because `:windo` expects a `{cmd}`.

What is in vimscript a `{cmd}` which does nothing (similar to `pass` in Python)?

**UPDATED VERSION**
As Luc Hermitte pointed out there is no need for an else branch: `:windo` does not complain. However, the `:windo` command had to be inside an `:execute` to avoid calling the placement of the cursor more often than needed, namely only once after `:windo` has finished:

```
if exists('##OptionSet')
  augroup Vinegar_redraw_netrw_windows
    autocmd!
    autocmd OptionSet wildignore,suffixes let s:currwin=winnr() |
            \ | execute "windo if &ft=='netrw' | execute \"normal \<C-L>\" | endif"
            \ | execute s:currwin . 'wincmd w'
  augroup END
endif
```

Comment: Isn't `windo` already receiving the `:if` command? Isn't it enough for it? When executed directly from the command-line, I have no error with `:windo if &ft != 'qf'| execute "normal \<c-l>" | endif`. BTW: I guess `CTRL-L` is not what you're really wanting to execute as it redraws the whole screen. No need to execute it dozens of time.

Comment: It looks like you are right that `:windo if ... | exe ... | endif`  does not need an else branch. Mmh, I can't get my error back. I have also added a silent to `windo` which removed some weird output from the  commandline output. Regarding `CTRL-L` redrawing the whole screen: I only want to do a redraw if there is at least one netrw window. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LucHermitte Are you sure that also `CTRL-L` (`<Plug>NetrwRefresh`) of netrw is executed for all windows? According to the flickering of only a single netrw window I would assume this is not the case.

Comment: @LucHermitte I realized now that all commands added with a `|` are executed by `:windo` . I think I should have asked how to end the `:windo` commands so that  `exe currwin ...` is not run more often than needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redraw only if there is a netrw windows, instead, I'd `filter()` the windows (`range(1, winnr('$'))`) with a `getwinvar(v:val, "&ft") == "netrw"`

```
if !empty(
\     filter(
\       range(1, winnr('$')),
\       'getwinvar(v:val, "&ft") == "netrw" && .......'
\   ))
   redraw
endif
```

This way, no need to remember the current window.

EDIT: Given the need to execute `<Plug>NetrwRefresh` in the netrw window, it becomes:

```
let netrw_win = filter(
\       range(1, winnr('$')),
\       'getwinvar(v:val, "&ft") == "netrw" && .......'
\   )
" a for loop may be a better choice in case there are several netrw windows
if !empty(netrw_win)
    let crt_win = winnr()
    try
        " I'm not sure about the quotes in the next line
        execute netrw_win[0] . "windo normal \<Plug>NetrwRefresh"
    finally
        execute crt_win . 'wincmd w'
    endtry
endif
```

Given the complexity, it'd be best to put that code into a function.

Note: another advantage of such solutions: it'll trigger less events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already a solution but I will certainly check if yours has some advantages. BTW I should have been more specific: it should be `<Plug>NetrwRefresh` for the netrw windows not the builtin `redraw`. netrw maps this by default to `CTRL-L`.

Comment: OK. In that case, it'll be more complex: the `CTRL-L` has to be done in the netrw window.